# Modifying a list element from within another element of the same list

Tags: r

I  want to create a list (basically an object with a custom class) that holds a database in one of the elements and a function in another element. After initializing the list I want to be able to call the function and have it modify the element that holds the database. Here is an example of what I mean

```
newObject<- function(dataSet){
  rtrn <- list()
  rtrn$dataHolder <- dataSet
  rtrn$addition <- function(numberToAdd){
    rtrn$dataHolder <- rtrn$dataHolder + numberToAdd
  }
  class(rtrn) <- "customClass" 
  return(rtrn)
}

x <- newObject(c(1,2,3))
x$addition(1)
```

Calling the addition() method doesn't actually modify the dataHolder element. I've tried <<- as an assignment operator as well (since I am modifying variable outside of the function), but that didn't seem to work either

Comment: I do not understand you logic. Why do not think in term of func prog/mathematical function where you simply define a function taking as argument a list, a field, a number and return this list field increased by the number?

Comment: By the way it is extremely bad to call a function "newObject". Use rather verb/action which describe clearly the action of your function.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. "newObject" is just for this example, meant to use it as an object constructor. Regarding the functional programming suggestion, that is what I'm using right now, but I was just wondering if I can contain the methods within the object - I was thinkinh it would make it easier to read if I have multiple objects holding different databases and all I have to do to process those datasets is just call a method already stored in those objects.

Comment: In general, it's bad to bring OOP habits when programming in R, which is a functional programming language. However, if you really need to use features of OOP languages, see `?setRefClass`. You can define your class having methods modifying the target object (as in OOP).

Comment: If a unique atomic function not linked to the object is doing this task, it is also very clear. You are reasonning in term of oriented object programming. If you really want to stick to this paradigm, forget R. Since it is more a functional programming langage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is almost a [closure](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures). If you correct your "class" to:

```
newObject<- function(dataSet) {
  dataHolder <- dataSet
  addition <- function(numberToAdd){
    dataHolder <<- dataHolder + numberToAdd
  }
  getdata <- function() {
    dataHolder
  } 

  rtrn <- list(addition = addition, getdata = getdata)
  class(rtrn) <- "customClass" 
  return(rtrn)
}
```

you get close to what you want:

```
x <- newObject(c(1,2,3))
x$getdata()
[1] 1 2 3  
x$addition(1)
x$getdata()
[1] 2 3 4
```

Since you defined your own [class](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html), you can also define a print function:

```
print.customClass <- function(x){ print(x$getdata()) }
```

And see the "interior" by

```
x
[1] 2 3 4
```